# Deactivate console messages

Tags: netbeans

I'm currently working on a project and an I used several print commands in order to see if all is going well. 
But all these prints take some execution time and since the program is running well I was wondering if there is a way to comment or delete all of those commands at once.

Comment: Please provide more information, like programming language you use. What version of netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can perform a "Replace in Projects...".

Presuming you code in JAVA:

- Goto "Edit > Replace in Projects"
- Set "Containing Text" to `System.out.print`
- Set "Match" to Literal
- Set "Replace with" to `//System.out.print`
- Choose your Scope (Project)
- Hit Continue

It is easy as that. Not even a need for Regular expression.

Have Fun.

Comment: What about loops used for the print. Because I'm using arrays

Comment: You might need a regular expression then. There is a good testing tool in Replace in Projects, when you select Regular Expression as Scope and click on (test). Please understand that I cannot give you a regular expression just like that. It depends on how you write your loops and how they are distinguishable from other loops. Whould be a good Idea to ask another question specific on the regular expression you need. I am not a regular expression guru and therefore not the right person to help you out on this.